# Find the string from True operator

Tags: r

I know that which function returns the value. Like in this code

```
A = c('Rida', 'Amna');
B = c('Rida', 'Fatima');
X = A == B;
print(which(X))
# [1] 1
```

This is the result i get, I want that it show **Rida** not **1**

Comment: Try `A[A == B]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `match` and extract

```
A[match(A, B, nomatch = 0)]
#[1] "Rida"
```